# ios Right way to free 2 dimensional memory allocated via calloc

Tags: ios, c, free, calloc

I have a iOS app. I allocate 2d memory and then deallocate using free function. Is this the right way to free? Recently I had crash pointing to free statement. Should I be releasing buf[i] in loop?

```
+(int**) initArr:(int) Nr:( int) Nc 
{
int ** buf;
  buf = calloc(Nr,sizeof(int*));

for(int i = 0; i < Nr; i++)
{
    buf[i] = calloc(Nc,sizeof(int));

}
//Funny Processing 

//Release
for(int i = 0; i < Nr; i++)
    free(buf[i]);
free(buf);
}
```

Here is the error message

```
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x328b87ec _sigtramp + 48
3 libsystem_c.dylib 0x328ae20e pthread_kill + 54
4 libsystem_c.dylib 0x328a729e abort + 94
5 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32862380 free + 380
6 MyApp 0x0009be52 +[clsGlobalHelper resizeImageAvg:::] (clsGlobalHelper.m:300)
```

Comment: The approach you're taking is a reasonable one. How is `buf` declared? Also, what is the exact message? Have you put a breakpoint on `malloc_debug_break`? Doing so will tell you exactly when the memory system realizes you've made an error, which can be really useful.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the code - I just updated the buf declaration.. Was trying to give only relevant code. This piece of code works fine on simulator and 3gs but start crashing at free statement in 4s. I know for sure that in vc++ this is how you deallocate. But not sure about ios.

Comment: `calloc`/`free` work the same in iOS as they do in VC++. What's the exact error message you're getting when the crash happens? Have you tried the breakpoint on `malloc_debug_break`?

Comment: I just edited with error message i get via testflightapp. I have not tried malloc_debug_break. I am reading through to understand what it is and then I will try... but might not be of much use as problem does not happen in simulator or the phone which is physically connected to my mac.

Comment: Hello Marcelo - Line 300 is free(buf[i]); its in loop. (Was away from my mac so took long time to get back)